# Adding a node under a existing node in XML using XPATH

Tags: java, xml

Below is the XML I have

```
         <TrustFrameworkPolicy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06" PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0" TenantId="{Settings:Tenant}" PolicyId="B2C_1A_User_MigrationClients" PublicPolicyUri="http://{Settings:Tenant}/B2C_1A_User_MigrationClients" DeploymentMode="{Settings:DeploymentMode}" UserJourneyRecorderEndpoint="urn:journeyrecorder:applicationinsights">
              <BuildModel>
                     <RestSchema>
                            <CustType Id="regular.type1">
                                  <DataType>string</DataType>
                            </CustType>
                            <CustType Id="regular.type2">
                                  <DataType>string</DataType>
                            </CustType>

                     </RestSchema>
              </BuildModel>
        </TrustFrameworkPolicy>
```

I have to add new nodes under "RestSchema"

This is how I want to create new

```
       <TrustFrameworkPolicy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
              xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06" PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0" TenantId="{Settings:Tenant}" PolicyId="B2C_1A_User_MigrationClients" PublicPolicyUri="http://{Settings:Tenant}/B2C_1A_User_MigrationClients" DeploymentMode="{Settings:DeploymentMode}" UserJourneyRecorderEndpoint="urn:journeyrecorder:applicationinsights">
               <BuildModel>
                 <RestSchema>
                        <CustType Id="regular.type1">
                              <DataType>string</DataType>
                        </CustType>
                        <CustType Id="regular.type2">
                              <DataType>string</DataType>
                        </CustType>
                        <CustType Id="regular.Command-Nest.type1">
                              <DataType>string</DataType>
                        </CustType>
                        <CustType Id="regular.Command-Nest.type2">
                              <DataType>string</DataType>
                        </CustType>
                 </RestSchema>
          </BuildModel>
    </TrustFrameworkPolicy>
```

How can I do it using XPATH. I have to create this type of structure in the EXISTING XML under.

I know how to track down to the  tag I just need to know how I can create these in java using XPATH.

Comment: Check out my answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67109521/add-new-node-under-an-existing-node-in-xml-in-java/67577041#67577041
Seems this question is a duplicate.